# Erlang with Chumak dying when being sent a large amount of data at once

Tags: erlang, chumak

I have an OTP-based program that uses Chumak for ZMQ.  The server has a pull socket, and the client has a push socket.  Everything works well in normal conditions.

The Python client sends several ZMQ messages a second.  If the connection between the client and server breaks, the client saves the messages to send after the connection is reestablished.

If the connection between the client and server breaks, and is reestablished quickly (say, within a couple of minutes), everything is fine.  If the connection breaks for a relatively long time (about 15 minutes in a test), the Erlang server dies with the message 'Killed'.  No other details are provided on the console.

Why might this be?

Comment: Can you see the RAM/CPU usage of server before crash? I think that it consumes lots of resources in a few time and OS kills it.

Comment: @Pouriya - credible theory - why would it consume so much memory though?  There are many messages from the server but they're small (1k each for example)